# How To Install Craft Locally Using XAMPP Without Reading From Web Directory

Tags: craft3

I'm just starting off working with craft and haven't had much of an issue installing the set and getting things configured locally. I'm using XAMPP but noticed once the installation completes the URL reads from the /web directory. Is there a way of removing this?

Initially I did try to set the base URL with the @web value but it now seems that this isn't acceptable in the most recent release.

Looking online the documentation or installation videos are pretty dated so there isn't really anything relevant to use as reference material to solve the problem.

So for example my local site currently reads from the following URL by default http://localhost/dev/craftycoffee2022/web/

When I want it to read from http://localhost/dev/craftycoffee2022

I'm sure this is a quick solution with .env or .htaccess mod or something.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

In XAMPP, you want to point the webserver to the `web` directory of your Craft project, so the web server will serve files from that directory. Will anything in this post help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902887/how-to-configuring-a-xampp-web-server-for-different-root-directory